# How do I change an ISO 8601 into a normal datetime without using any module in Python?

Tags: python, string

I need to change this `2019-11-21T19:05:47` into `21/11/2019 19h 05m 47s` by using only `.split()` and `.join()` functions. I know I can divide the string at T but from that, I can't go on.

Comment: What effort have you made to try to solve the problem. You have listed the tools you need to use so this sounds like a homework problem. You alreayd know you can use T as the split for date and time. next you need to thinks about how you can split the date? maybe `-`? then how can you split the time? Maybe `:`? now you will have all components of the datetime in variables you can use join to join them back up in any order you want

Comment: All right, thanks, I know that´s an easy problem but for me it's not. If I have had to ask for help is because I realy need it.

Answer (score 0):

In [1]: t = "2019-11-21T19:05:47"

In [2]: parts = t.split('T')

In [3]: y,m,d = parts[0].split('-')

In [4]: h,M,S = parts[1].split(':')

In [5]: t = f"{m}/{d}/{y} {h}h {M}m {S}s"

In [6]: t
Out[6]: '21/11/2019 19h 05m 47s'

But I think you should use datatime module for such problems, because it is well tested and resist to potential errors. My solution doesn't have any validation and tests!